# Hide the left pane and the top bar in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04

I want to hide the left pane and the top bar of ubuntu (gnome) , so that i only have the desktop .
How can i do this using the console ?
if it's not possible from console , how to do it from settings ?

Comment: I assume you are using unity. I don't think it is possible in unity. In any case it will not be simple. I would recommend you try a different window manager. Maybe cinnamon, mate, xfce or openbox.

Comment: i am using gnome

Comment: you want to hide top left corner right?

Comment: yes , and if possible top right too (which has the time and stuff )